# comparing user signature using guestures

Tags: android, gesture

In my application , user will input signature and the next time it will compare and do the authentication.

I have see question on SO but I cant find how we compare. If we use gesture and store file as image , Its not correct as next time user might sign with little variation.

I have tried comparing using Gestures it self but , firstly multistroke is not working properly and second predictions are not perfect.

To add gesture to library :
    public void addGesture() {
            if (mGesture != null) {

```
            final GestureLibrary store = getStore();
            store.addGesture("ges", mGesture);
            store.save();
            setResult(RESULT_OK);

            final String path = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                    "gestures").getAbsolutePath();
            Toast.makeText(this,"success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
        }           
    }
```

Comparing :

```
public void onGesturePerformed(GestureOverlayView overlay, Gesture gesture) {
        ArrayList<Prediction> predictions = mLibrary.recognize(gesture);
        Log.e("predictions","predictions----"+predictions.size());
        // We want at least one prediction
        if (predictions.size() > 0) {
            Prediction prediction = predictions.get(0);
            // We want at least some confidence in the result
            Log.e("SCORE","SCORE----"+prediction.score);
            if (prediction.score > 1.0) {
                // Show the spell
                Toast.makeText(this, prediction.name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

Can anyone suggest something regaurding this.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do it reduce predication score from to say 0.7.

```
if (prediction.score > 0.7) {                 // Show the spell                 Toast.makeText(this, prediction.name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();             }
```

i think this should solve your problem.

Comment: should i reduce or increase , as the doc say score less than 1.0 is poor?

Comment: You should reduce it. becoz signature varies a bit always. otherwise it wont match.

Comment: oo.. what you can do it just try to print predication.score check the value of it.

Comment: Ok , have u tried nything like this , coz when I writing name , "i" dont is not possible.